# Problems on data type indices that uses list concatenation

Tags: agda

I'm having a nasty problem with a formalisation of a theorem that uses a data type that have some constructors whose indices have list concatenation. When I try to use emacs mode to case split, Agda returns the following error message:

```
I'm not sure if there should be a case for the constructor
o-success, because I get stuck when trying to solve the following
unification problems (inferred index ≟ expected index):
  e₁ o e'' , x₁ ++ x'' ++ y₁ ≟ e o e' , x ++ x' ++ y
  suc (n₂ + n'') , x₁ ++ x'' ≟ m' , p''
when checking that the expression ? has type
suc (.n₁ + .n') == .m' × .x ++ .x' == p'
```

Since the code is has more than a small number of lines, I put it on the following gist:

https://gist.github.com/rodrigogribeiro/976b3d5cc82c970314c2

Any tip is appreciated.

Best,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27045886/pattern-match-on-specialised-constructors/).

However you want to unify `xs1 ++ xs2 ++ xs3` with `ys1 ++ ys2 ++ ys3`, but `_++_` is not a constructor — it's a function, and it's not injective. Consider this simplified example:

```
data Bar {A : Set} : List A -> Set where
  bar : ∀ xs {ys} -> Bar (xs ++ ys)

ex : ∀ {A} {zs : List A} -> Bar zs -> Bar zs -> List A
ex (bar xs) b = {!!}
```

`b` is of type `Bar (xs ++ .ys)`, but `b` is not necessarily equal to `bar .xs`, so you can't pattern-match like this. Here are two `Bar`s, which have equal types but different values:

```
ok : ∃₂ λ (b1 b2 : Bar (tt ∷ [])) -> b1 ≢ b2
ok = bar [] , bar (tt ∷ []) , λ ()
```

This is because `xs1 ++ xs2 ≡ ys1 ++ ys2` doesn't imply `xs1 ≡ ys1 × xs2 ≡ ys2` in general.

But it's possible to generalize an index. You can use the technique described by Vitus at the link above, or you can use this simple combinator, which forgets the index:

```
generalize : ∀ {α β} {A : Set α} (B : A -> Set β) {x : A} -> B x -> ∃ B
generalize B y = , y
```

E.g.

```
ex : ∀ {A} {zs : List A} -> Bar zs -> Bar zs -> List A
ex {A} (bar xs) b with generalize Bar b
... | ._ , bar ys = xs ++ ys
```

After all, are you sure your lemma is true?

**UPDATE**

Some remarks first.

Your `empty` case states

```
empty : forall x -> G :: (emp , x) => (1 , x)
```

that the `empty` parser parses the whole string. It should be

```
empty : forall x -> G :: (emp , x) => (1 , [])
```

as in the paper.

Your definition of `o-fail1` contains this part:

```
(n , fail ∷ o)
```

but `fail` fails everything, so it should be `(n , fail ∷ [])`. With this representation you would probably need decidable equality on `A` to finish the lemma, and proofs would be dirty. Clean and idiomatic way to represent something, that can fail, is to wrap it in the `Maybe` monad, so here is my definition of `_::_=>_`:

```
data _::_=>_ {n} (G : Con n) : Foo n × List A -> Nat × Maybe (List A) -> Set where
  empty       : ∀ {x}     -> G :: emp   ,  x      => 1 , just []
  sym-success : ∀ {a x}   -> G :: sym a , (a ∷ x) => 1 , just (a ∷ [])
  sym-failure : ∀ {a b x} -> ¬ (a == b) -> G :: sym a , b ∷ x => 1 , nothing
  var         : ∀ {x m o} {v : Fin (suc n)}
              -> G :: lookup v G , x => m , o -> G :: var v , x => suc m , o
  o-success : ∀ {e e' x x' y n n'}
            -> G :: e      , x ++ x' ++ y => n            , just x
            -> G :: e'     ,      x' ++ y => n'           , just x'
            -> G :: e o e' , x ++ x' ++ y => suc (n + n') , just (x ++ x')
  o-fail1   : ∀ {e e' x x' y n}
            -> G :: e      , x ++ x' ++ y => n     , nothing
            -> G :: e o e' , x ++ x' ++ y => suc n , nothing
  o-fail2   : ∀ {e e' x x' y n n'}
            -> G :: e      , x ++ x' ++ y => n            , just x
            -> G :: e'     ,      x' ++ y => n'           , nothing
            -> G :: e o e' , x ++ x' ++ y => suc (n + n') , nothing
```

Here is the `lemma`:

```
postulate
  cut : ∀ {α} {A : Set α} -> ∀ xs {ys zs : List A} -> xs ++ ys == xs ++ zs -> ys == zs

mutual
  aux : ∀ {n} {G : Con n} {e e' z x x' y n n' m' p'}
      -> z == x ++ x' ++ y
      -> G :: e      , z       => n  , just x
      -> G :: e'     , x' ++ y => n' , just x'
      -> G :: e o e' , z       => m' , p'
      -> suc (n + n') == m' × just (x ++ x') == p'
  aux {x = x} {x'} {n = n} {n'} r pr1 pr2 (o-success {x = x''} pr3 pr4) with x | n | lemma pr1 pr3
  ... | ._ | ._ | refl , refl rewrite cut x'' r with x' | n' | lemma pr2 pr4
  ... | ._ | ._ | refl , refl = refl , refl
  aux ...

  lemma : ∀ {n m m'} {G : Con n} {f x p p'}
        -> G :: f , x => m , p -> G :: f , x => m' , p' -> m == m' × p == p'
  lemma (o-success pr1 pr2)  pr3            = aux refl pr1 pr2 pr3
  lemma ...
```

The proof proceeds as follows:

1. We generalize the type of `lemma`'s `pr3` in an auxiliary function as in the Vitus' answer. Now it's possible to pattern-match on `pr3`.
2. We prove, that the first parser in `lemma'`s `pr3` (called also `pr3` in the `aux`) produces the same output as `pr1`.
3. After some rewriting, we prove that the second parser in `lemma`'s `pr3` (called `pr4` in the `aux`) produces the same output as `pr2`.
4. And since `pr1` and `pr3` produce the same output, and `pr2` and `pr4` produce the same output, `o-success pr1 pr2` and `o-success pr3 pr4` produce the same output, so we put `refl , refl`.

The [code](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/PEG-lemma/one.agda). I didn't prove the `o-fail1` and `o-fail2` cases, but they should be similar.

**UPDATE**

Amount of boilerplate can be reduced by

1. Fixing the definitions of the `fail` cases, which contain redundant information.
2. Returning `Maybe (List A)` instead of `Nat × Maybe (List A)`. You can compute this `Nat` recursively, if needed.
3. Using the `inspect` idiom instead of auxiliary functions.

I don't think there is a simpler solution. The [code](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/PEG-lemma/two.agda).

Comment: This lemma development is a simplified version of a formalisation that I'm trying using Agda. The lemma (in paper version) is obviously true. Also, I believe that my representation of the formalisation is adequate. So, I think that the problem is with the concatenation that must appear as an index of the data type. I'll try your tip for generalize and also read Vitus answer that you have provided. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: The paper is not Agda related and its name is: Parser expression grammars: a recognition-based syntactic foundation. My problem is to represent parser expression grammars and the lemma I'm trying to prove is that semantics of PEG is deterministic.

Comment: Sorry about bothering you with these beginner questions, but I do not understand how could forgetting an index help me to prove the previous problematic lemma.

Comment: @Rodrigo Ribeiro, it cannot, I mentioned it for the exhaustiveness, sorry for the ambiguity. I updated the answer.

Comment: Very thanks for your help! It worked perfectly... I'd never think in such solution...

Comment: @Rodrigo Ribeiro, my pleasure. BTW, you can get rid of this mutual block by defining `aux` in a `where` clause like this: `lemma (o-success pr1 pr2)  pr3  = aux refl pr1 pr2 pr3 where aux : ... ; aux = ...`.

Comment: A last question related to this code: Is there some way to avoid such boilerplate lemmas (like aux) needed to finish this proof ?