# Agda: pattern matching equal variables?

Tags: types, functional-programming, agda, dependent-type

As a learning experience, I'm trying to implement a verified regular-expression matcher using continuation-passing style in Agda, based on the one proposed in [this paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/papers/regexp/jfp.pdf).

I've got a type for regular expressions defined like this:

```agda
data RE :  Set where
  ε : RE 
  ∅ : RE 
  Lit : Char -> RE 
  _+_ : RE -> RE -> RE
  _·_ :  RE -> RE -> RE
  _* : RE -> RE
```

And a type for a proof that a string matches an RE like this:

```agda
data REMatch : List Char -> RE -> Set where
  EmptyMatch : REMatch [] ε
  LitMatch : (c : Char) -> REMatch (c ∷ []) (Lit c)
  ...
  ConcatMatch : 
    (s1 : List Char) (s2 : List Char ) (r1 : RE) (r2 : RE)
    -> REMatch s1 r1
    -> REMatch s2 r2
    -> REMatch (s1 ++ s2) (r1 · r2)
```

I'm trying to write a correctness proof for my matcher, but I'm getting type errors on my pattern matches, before I even try to have a proof:

```agda
accCorrect : 
  (r : RE) (s : List Char) (s1 : List Char) (s2 : List Char) (k : (List Char -> Bool)) 
  -> ( (s1 ++ s2) ≡ s)
  -> (REMatch s1 r)
  -> (k s2 ≡ true)
  -> (acc r s k ≡ true )
accCorrect ε [] [] [] k _ EmptyMatch kproof = kproof
accCorrect (r1 · r2) s s1 s2 k splitProof (ConcatMatch s1' s1'' r1' r2' subMatch1 subMatch2 ) kproof = ?
```

However, this gives the following error:

```
r2' != r2 of type RE
when checking that the pattern
ConcatMatch s1' s1'' r1' r2' subMatch1 subMatch2 has type
REMatch s1 (r1 · r2)
```

However, if I replace the underscores `r2'` with  `r2`, I get a "repeated variables" error.

There is no way to construct a match for `(r1 · r2)` except the `ConcatMatch` constructor.

**My question:**

How do I convince the type-checker that `r2` and `r2'` are equal, from within a pattern match? Any argument of type `REMatch s1 (r1 · r2)` must be constructed with the `ConcatMatch` constructor using arguments `r1` and `r2`, but I don't know how to prove that this is the case from within a pattern match.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's why Agda has dot patterns:

```
accCorrect : 
  (r : RE) (s : List Char) (s1 : List Char) (s2 : List Char) (k : (List Char -> Bool)) 
  -> ( (s1 ++ s2) ≡ s)
  -> (REMatch s1 r)
  -> (k s2 ≡ true)
  -> (acc r s k ≡ true )
accCorrect (.r1 · .r2) s ._ s2 k splitProof (ConcatMatch s1' s1'' r1 r2 subMatch1 subMatch2 ) kproof = {!!}
accCorrect _ _ _ = {!!}
```

I.e. just place `.` before the expression that supposed to be inferred. Or you can (and should) use implicit arguments:

```
accCorrect' : 
  {r : RE} (s : List Char) {s1 : List Char} (s2 : List Char) (k : (List Char -> Bool)) 
  -> ( (s1 ++ s2) ≡ s)
  -> (REMatch s1 r)
  -> (k s2 ≡ true)
  -> (acc r s k ≡ true )
accCorrect' s s2 k splitProof (ConcatMatch s1' s1'' r1 r2 subMatch1 subMatch2 ) kproof = {!!}
accCorrect' _ _ _ _ _ = {!!}
```

However you'll probably encounter more complex problems, because you have touched the green slime (the terminology is due to Conor McBride):

> The presence of ‘green slime’ — defined functions in the return types
>   of constructors — is a danger sign.

Here is a similar and illustrative [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260874/problems-on-data-type-indices-that-uses-list-concatenation).