# Agda unification over a list

Tags: list, agda, unification

I am doing a project that proves some properties of Regular expressions.
Here is part of my code

`⇨` here means derives, `Regexp ⇨ word` means a Regexp can derive a word

```
Σ : Set
Σ* : List Σ
```

Below defines the case when the concatenation `e₁ ∙ e₂` can derive a word `w` if `e₁ ⇨ w₁`, `e₂ ⇨ w₂` and `w ≡ w₁ ++ w₂`

```
data _⇨_ : RegExp Σ → Σ* → Set where
 con : {e₁ e₂ : RegExp Σ}{w w₁ w₂ : Σ*} → w ≡ w₁ ++ w₂ → e₁ ⇨ w₁ → e₂ ⇨ w₂ → e₁ ∙ e₂ ⇨ w
```

This is proving that if `w ≡ w₁ ++ []` and (e₁ cannot derives w₁) than (e₁.e₂ cannot derive w)

```
¬e₁∙e₂⇨xs[]ˡ : {e₁ e₂ : RegExp Σ}{w w₁ : Σ*} → w ≡ w₁ ++ [] → ¬ (e₁ ⇨ w₁) → ¬ (e₁ ∙ e₂ ⇨ w)
¬e₁∙e₂⇨xs[]ˡ refl ¬e₁⇨w₁ (con {w₂ = []} refl e₁⇨w₁ e₂⇨[]) = ¬e₁⇨w₁ e₁⇨w₁
```

However, the `refl` in the `con refl e₁⇨w₁ e₂⇨[]` does not type check, because Agda cannot unify the `w₁` in `¬e₁∙e₂⇨xs[]ˡ` with the `w₁` in `¬ (e₁ ∙ e₂ ⇨ w)` The error message is here:

```
w₁ != w₂ of type List Σ
when checking that the pattern refl has type w₁ ++ [] ≡ w₂ ++ []
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you pattern-match on `w ≡ w₁ ++ []` you are doomed, because `w` gets unified with `w₁ ++ []`, `e₁ ∙ e₂ ⇨ w` becomes `e₁ ∙ e₂ ⇨ w₁ ++ []` and you can't pattern-match on that.

`_++_` is not injective and `w₁ ++ [] ≡ w₁' ++ w₂'` doesn't entail `w₁ ≡ w₁' × [] ≡ w₂'` — in general there are other ways to unify those two expressions.

Your lemma is isomorphic to

```
¬e₁∙e₂⇨xs[]ˡ : {e₁ e₂ : RegExp Σ}{w : Σ*} → ¬ (e₁ ⇨ w) → ¬ (e₁ ∙ e₂ ⇨ w)
```

which looks false to me.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260874/problems-on-data-type-indices-that-uses-list-concatenation/29270415#29270415) for a similar problem.