# Stuck on unification problems during case splitting

Tags: agda

Suppose we have the following code:

```
open import Data.Fin
open import Data.Nat

data SType : ℕ → Set where

variable
  ℓ : ℕ
  ι : Fin ℓ
  τ τ' : SType ℓ

infixl 5 _,_
data Ctx : ℕ → Set where
  ⊘   : Ctx zero
  _,_ : Ctx ℓ → SType ℓ → Ctx (suc ℓ)

variable Γ : Ctx ℓ

postulate weaken : SType ℓ → SType (suc ℓ)

infix 4 _∈_at_
data _∈_at_ : SType ℓ → Ctx ℓ → Fin ℓ → Set where
  ∈-zero : weaken τ ∈ Γ , τ at zero
  ∈-suc  : τ ∈ Γ at ι
         → weaken τ ∈ Γ , τ' at suc ι
```

which models a tiny part of a well-scoped representation of a type system (and I'm keeping `weaken` `postulate`d and `SType` not having any constructors for the sake of brevity).

Now suppose we want to write a function that's basically an "inverse" of the `∈-suc` constructor:

```
∈-chop : weaken τ ∈ Γ , τ' at suc ι
       → τ ∈ Γ at ι
∈-chop ∈ = {! !}
```

Now, if we try to split on `∈`, Agda will get all doubting and hesitant:

```
I'm not sure if there should be a case for the constructor ∈-suc,
because I get stuck when trying to solve the following unification
problems (inferred index ≟ expected index):
  {suc τ.ℓ₁} ≟ {suc τ.ℓ₂}
  weaken τ₁ ≟ weaken τ₂
  Γ₁ , τ'' ≟ Γ₂ , τ'''
  suc ι₁ ≟ suc ι₂
when checking that the expression ? has type τ ∈ Γ at ι
```

Why is it not sure, and what's the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the Green Slime.

[Quoting](https://lists.chalmers.se/pipermail/agda/2017/009739.html) Jesper Cockx:

> The error message "cannot generalize over the indices" is thrown by Agda when it encounters a unification problem of the form `c us =?= c vs` where `c` is a constructor of an indexed datatype, but the indices in the *type* of this equation are something other than distinct variables (i.e. they
> should be fully general). If they are not, Agda tries to apply a technique called higher-dimensional unification (see our CPP 2017 paper) to bring them in a fully general form. However, this unfortunately doesn't always succeed, for example in your code it gets stuck on the *+* function in the index of `con`.
>
> One way to fix your problem would be to get rid of the 'green slime' in the type of `con`: it's better to use only variables and constructors in the indices of your datatypes, and use explicit proofs of equality for the heavier work.

You can check that this is indeed the case by making `weaken` a constructor of `SType`, which then allows you to define `∈-chop` by pattern matching like you want.

Matching on `∈-suc` amounts to solving

```
weaken τ ∈ Γ , τ' at suc ι =?= weaken _τ ∈ _Γ , _τ' at suc _ι
```

where the LHS is the type that you provided in the type signature and the RHS is the inferred type of `∈-suc` where each implicit variable got turned into a meta. Now unifying, say, `suc ι` and `suc _ι` is no problem, since constructors are injective, but functions are generally not (see the first part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29270415/3237465)) and so when `weaken` is a function you can't unify `weaken τ` with `weaken _τ`.

You can use explicit equality to get around the issue:

```
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
 
infix 4 _∈_at_
data _∈_at_ : SType ℓ → Ctx ℓ → Fin ℓ → Set where
  ∈-zero : τ' ≡ weaken τ → τ' ∈ Γ , τ at zero
  ∈-suc  : τ' ≡ weaken τ
         → τ ∈ Γ at ι
         → τ' ∈ Γ , τ at suc ι
```

That allows you to pattern match in `∈-chop` even when `weaken` is a function.

Answer (score 2):

Your definitions seem to imply that, in `∈-chop` there are no possible value for `τ` which can be seen as follows:

```
∈-chop : ∀ {Γ τ ι} → weaken τ ∈ Γ , τ' at suc ι → τ ∈ Γ at ι
∈-chop {τ = ()}
```

This does not directly answer your question but it's probably not the indented behavior which could ultimately solve your problem.

Comment: That's because `SType` is empty. In the real code it probably has a bunch of constructors, so this is unrelated.

Comment: it might not be completely unrelated because it's often by pattern matching on other arguments that problems of kind "I'm not sure if there should be a case ..." are solved, here we cannot because of the empty type.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I've updated my question to note that `SType` indeed has a bunch of constructors.